# Connecting two models in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I have two models, each stored in a separate VBO. What I want do is to link them so that rotating one rotates the other, while still leaving the other connected to the first model. What I do now is have three model matrices: one main one for the entire object, and one for each of the models so that they can be translated in relation to the main matrix. When I do this however, the two models disconnect if I rotate them. How would I link the two models so that they stay connected during rotation or translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would do it like this:

```
glLoadMatrix( mainMatrix );
glPushMatrix();
glMultMatrix( firstModelMatrix );
drawFirstModel();
glPopMatrix();
glMultMatrix( secondModelMatrix );
drawSecondModel();
```

Of course, if you change `firstModelMatrix` or `secondModelMatrix`, the two models might be rendered disconnected. But than, this is what you intent. If you want to stay them connected, only change the `mainMatrix`.

However, note that those matrix operations are deprecated. Nevertheless you should be able to get the trick from the code.

EDIT: Given that you have a head and a body. You want to rotate the head. Than its all about how your head-matrix is computed, it is particularly important in which order you apply the translation and rotation. I guess, right now you have something like this:

```
HeadMatrix = Rotation * Translation
```

But what you need is this in order to keep the head on top of the body:

```
HeadMatrix = Translation * Rotation
```

Comment: This is basicly what I do. I do it with shaders however. What I have is a head model, and a body model. I translate the head model to be above the body model. However, if I rotate this then the head model will not stay attached to the body model, at least not in its original place on the body model.

Comment: Thanks! That is not exactly what I was looking for, but it helped me get there. I was trying to rotate the entire model while keeping the head connected. That wasn't working. By multiplying by the headmatrix then the mainmatrix I was able to fix it. Before I was multiplying by the mainmatrix then the head matrix.

Comment: You're welcome. You must know that matrix multiplications are not commutative. This makes it important, in which order you apply them.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have two models. All you have are two buffers of bytes, that become geometry only when combined with a glDrawArrays or glDrawElements call that accesses the data in the buffers and interprets it as triangles.

OpenGL doesn't know what a "model" is. OpenGL doesn't maintain a scene or relationship between models. It's merely drawing points, lines or triangles to a framebuffer, each at a time, without any recollection of which other points, lines or triangles have been drawn before.

If you want a scene, you must maintain that yourself.